# why goroutine block main func in this http server?

Tags: go

I want to setup a http server with httprouter listening on two ports `8888` and `8080` just like the code below.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Welcome!\n")
}

func main() {
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/", Index)

    fmt.Println("listen on 8080")
    // this is where blocked
    go log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
    fmt.Println("listen on 8888")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8888", router))
}
```

But it doesn't work properly,my server only listen on `8080`.If I make some change:

```
go func() { log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router)) }()
```

It works finely both on `8080` and `8888`.So why? It's about `closure` or something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The function value and parameters are evaluated as usual in the calling goroutine

— [Go language spec, "Go statements"](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements).

You're creating a goroutine for the call to `log.Fatal`, but the *arguments* to `log.Fatal` are evaluated beforehand, in the main goroutine. And `Fatal`'s argument is the return value of `http.ListenAndServe`. So the new goroutine doesn't start until *after* `ListenAndServe` returns.

Answer (score 8):

Since `http.ListenAndServe()` is blocking, and in your scenario, there are two of them, then try to put one of them in a goroutine. The idea is to separate the execution of those two web server initialization statements into separate goroutine.

```
func main() {
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/", Index)

    go func() {
        fmt.Println("listen on 8080")
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
    }()

    fmt.Println("listen on 8888")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8888", router))
}
```